# Change design with Pyside2 - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I use Python 3.7 and Pyside2.

I would like to change color, font, background color... but I can not !

I import QtGui for design but I have the same error `'Window' object has no attribute 'setBrush'`

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QBrush, QPainterPath, QFont
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QDesktopWidget

import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Convertisseur de devises")
        self.setGeometry(700,300,700,300)
        self.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 127))

        self.setButton()
        self.center()

    def setButton(self):
        btn = QPushButton("Inverser Devises", self)
        btn.move(550,135)

    def center(self):
        qRect = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qRect.topLeft())

myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()

myapp.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

For exemple :

- **setButton** Remove the background color, borders, white writing ...
- **window** Change the background color

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the Painter just use a stylesheet. Qt stylesheets use CSS syntax and can be easily reused for multiple widgets. More info here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

In your case for example you could replace

```
self.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 127))
```

with

```
self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(0, 0, 127)')
```

to change the background color to Blue.

To make it reusable though it would make sense to put the Stylesheet into a seperate file. Place the stylesheet in the same folder as your Python file.

style.qss:

```
QWidget {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 127);
}

QPushButton {
    border: none;
    color: white;
}
```

And then replace

```
self.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 127))
```

with

```
# This gets the folder the Python file is in and creates the path for the stylesheet
stylesheet_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'style.qss')

with open(stylesheet_path, 'r') as f:
    self.setStyleSheet(f.read())
```

And since you set the style on the parent widget all child widgets (including your Button) will have the same style aswell.

Comment: Thanks, Hi, I think that I forgotten a step. I replaced _self.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 127))_ with your code and I add a new file **style.qss** with your code. But I have this error `No such file or directory: 'style.qss'`

Comment: Make sure the path to the `style.qss` is correct. If you just use `open('style.qss', 'r')` your working directory will have to be the same as the style file. I'll edit my post so you can just place the style.qss next to the python file.

Comment: Thank You so much, it's perfect !